# Is it possible to automatically replace multi-character Unicode symbols by one Unicode symbol?

Tags: python, unicode, nlp

U+006E (n), and U+0303 (a combining tilde) forms ñ, but the code point U+00F1 forms ñ:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

one = u'\xf1'
two = u'\x6e\u0303'
print(u"{} has len={}".format(one, len(one)))
print(u"{} has len={}".format(two, len(two)))
```

returning (edit: interesting - the style of the box below breaks it in my browser, showing the tilde not above the n)

```
ñ has len=1
ñ has len=2
```

I know that those two could have different meanings, but this is rather unlikely. I also know how to replace single examples in a complete text, but I guess there are many more than just the tilde.

**How can I replace all Unicode combinations by a single, equivalent single code point, where possible?**

(My usecase: I want to do NLP on Wikipedia. I want to have texts with at least 140 characters in terms of Unicode code points. Having examples like the one above are not too bad, but it would be desirable if this would not be the case.)

Comment: The term you need is "normalisation". See *[Unicode Normalization Forms](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)*.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize):

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> one = u'\xf1'
>>> two = u'\x6e\u0303'
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFC', one)
u'\xf1'
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFC', two)
u'\xf1'
```

Thank you, @[Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67392/richard)!